# read unsigned long from binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, readfile

I'm trying to read an `unsigned long` number from a binary file.
i'm doing this in this way:

```
    infile.open("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    char* U=new char[sizeof(unsigned long)];
    unsigned long out=0;
    infile.read(U, sizeof(unsigned long));
    out=static_cast<unsigned long>(*U);
    delete[] U;
    U=NULL;
    infile.close();
```

but result is not correct.
My data is `6A F2 6B 58 00 00 00 00` witch should be read as `1483469418` but out is `106` in my code which is just the first byte of data

What is the problem?
how should i correctly read an `unsigned long` from file?

Comment: What endian format are you expecting and what format are you using? This is very important to be aware of when dealing with multi-byte integer values.

Comment: You are just casting the first byte into an unsigned long. Besides, the method isn't portable anyway because of endanness.

Comment: @tadman: both file and system are LE

Comment: @A.S.H: how can I do that correctly & endianless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are casting a dereferenced value. I.e. only a `char` not full 4 bytes. `*U` is `106`.

You can read the data in without the intermediate buffer:

`infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&out), sizeof out);`

The difference is that here you are reinterpreting the pointer, not the value under it.

If you still want to use the buffer, it should be `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(U);`, this also reinterprets the pointer 1st, and then dereferences it. The key is to dereference a pointer of proper type. The type of pointer determines how many bytes are used for the value.

Comment: Any reason why new/wrong type of buffer is being used?  Why not just pass it into the value it already expects?  Endianess at least scares me with this...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand you. Using buffer is not wrong, I didn't say that. It's superfluous in OPs case, so I actually gave an example which stores the value directly into the variable. But if one wants to use the buffer, there is the 2nd option I gave. One can swap bytes prior to cast if needed, but OP doesn't seem to care about endianess.

Comment: Ah crap - my bad..  Didn't see what out was defined as - carry on then :)

Answer (score 3):

out=static_cast(*U); should be out=*(unsigned long *)(U);

It can be much simpler:

```
infile.open("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
unsigned long out=0;
infile.read((char *)&out, sizeof(out));
infile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `out=*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long *>(U);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to know whether the file (not the program) is big endian or little endian. Then read the bytes with fgetc() and reconsitute the number

so

```
  unsigned long read32be(FILE *fp)
  {
      unsigned long ch0, ch1, ch2 ch3;

      ch0 = fgetc(fp);
      ch1 = fgetc(fp);
      ch2 = fgetc(fp);
      ch3 = fgetc(fp);

      return (unsigned long) (ch0 << 24) | (ch1 << 16) | (ch2 << 8) | ch3
  }
```

Now it will work regardless of whether longs is 32 bits or 64, big_endian or little endian. If the *file* is little endian, swap the order of the fgetc()s.

Reading binary files portably is surprisingly tricky. I've put some code on github

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/ieee754

Comment: I'm gonna argue that this is c, not c++, and it's not helpful at all. Do you propose OP swap all IO routines to c? It won't work regardless of endianess. You need to manually alter the read order. You could do the same with OPs code. Just use `swap` on `U` contents.

Comment: It works regardless of the machine's endianness. It's not possible to parse a file correctly regardless of the file's endianness.

Comment: The original code also works regardless of machine endianess. It's illusory to separate those two things. What is important is machine/system vs file endianess. If both are there same there is no problem. If they are different you need to swap bytes. So yes, it is possible to read file correctly regardless of it's endianes. You need to read it on a machine with the same endianess. My point is, it is impossible to make a general case, and suggesting something works regardless of endianess with out any kind of conditional byte swapping is smokes and screens. You just moved the problem.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. You raise an important issue. Though, this is a half of answer, in `c`, and does not address and explain the problem OP had, at all. It is a completely orthogonal thing. That's why I don't particularly like it.